# Outlook calendar invite to sharepoint calender/event app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

We are a group who should be aware of mutual meetings booked via outlook, I want to reflect these meetings on our sharepoint site preferebly through a calendar app.

What are my options?

I have a specific group email (not a distribution list) can I use that for the calendar?

Should I make a group calendar?

Can I make a sharepoint list and invite through outloook?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually three ways to achieve this.

1.Use group calendar web part in the SharePoint page.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce

2.Embed the whole calendar page in the Outlook Web App with iframe codes. First you should add outlook.office.com in the allowed list via the steps in this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-or-restrict-the-ability-to-embed-content-on-sharepoint-pages-e7baf83f-09d0-4bd1-9058-4aa483ee137b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) and then use Embed webpart in the SharePoint online site page. You can use the iframe as follows.

```
<iframe src="https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/month" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="400px" width="600px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

3.Connect SharePoint classic calendar list to your Outlook, then sync these meetings from outlook into the contact list.
[image]